# How can we evaluate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, tensors

After half an hour of heroic efforts, I calculated, for a symmetric tensor $T$:

$$
\newcommand{a}{\alpha}
\newcommand{b}{\beta}
\newcommand{p}{\partial_}
\newcommand{s}{\sqrt {|g|}}
\newcommand{w}{\nabla_\b T_\a{}^\b}
\w = \frac 1 \s \p\b \left( \s T_\a{}^\b \right)
   + \frac 1 2 T_{\mu\nu} \p\a g^{\mu\nu}
$$

Now, how do I evaluate the following integral, where $V$ is an region in an $n$-dimensional manifold?

$$\int_V \w \s d^nx$$